# Amazon SES: Procedure for handling complaint notifications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I don't have a ton of experience with Amazon SES. For a client of mine, I maintain a small subscription list (about 1300 people) and I use Amazon SES to send messages through from the WordPress blog that this group is subscribed to, whenever there is a new post. Every so often I get complaint notifications from Amazon, but there is no identifying info to tell me who the complaint is from so that I can remove them from my list. How can I use those emails (or some other part of SES) to effectively remove these recipients? I have no intention of sending to anyone who doesn't want to receive these emails (even if they have not unsubscribed on the blog directly), but I can find no way of addressing these complaints.

The messages contain (in addition to the content of the email), information like the following:

```
User-Agent: ReturnPathFBL/1.0
Abuse-Type: complaint
Arrival-Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 10:22:08 +0000
Feedback-Type: abuse
Version: 1
Source-IP: 54.240.27.23
Original-Rcpt-To: 8516be265e1454635b9a5885efb329a4@comcast.net
Original-Mail-From: 0101015defb6e57b-8068a1db-1011-407e-af0c-1bf96aa38c5f-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com
Reported-Domain: comcast.net
```

**UPDATE**
This is maddening. I have now setup an endpoint on my server, and when subscribed to SNS topic I correctly receive logs that I have been subscribed. But then...NOTHING. I still get the useless emails, but I get zero SNS notifications, despite being verified. Still investigating.

**UPDATE II**
Success!! It turns out that setting up SNS (or email notifications) on the DOMAIN was meaningless. I had to set it up specifically on the EMAIL SENDING ADDRESS. This was CRUCIAL but not at all obvious (at least to me)

Comment: Can you write complaint messages from Amazon?

Comment: added more detail above, hope that is what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question been addressed in amazon blog.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/tag/abuse-complaint/

Make sure you are following the procedure to [handle bounces and complaints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/handling-bounces-and-complaints/) from amazon aws.

Comment: Thanks, but I already read both those articles, and they don't seem to have the info I am looking for: How I can identify which email bounced when I receive the notifications. However, I DID just find a setting that seems to indicate I can include original message headers in the notifications I get and just turned that on. I am hoping the next notification contains an actual email address so that I can simply unsubscribe that person, which is all I want to do.

Comment: Aws clearly mentioned SES configuration to handle bounce and complaint steps using each message id and sns/sqs as services. I have tested the sample email using simulator in SES. it works fine. FYI http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-examples.html ,  http://www.tothenew.com/blog/setting-aws-ses-bounce-notification/

Comment: I am already receiving notifications of bounces (via email), and that part is fine..they simply don't contain the info I need to be able to remove someone from a list.

Comment: I am not talking about email. Did you configure SNS to handle bounces/complaints in SES as mentioned in document?

Comment: if you are asking if I set up an endpoint on my server, no. And if I am reading the documentation correctly (and it is possible I am missing something), I should not have to. I just want to receive the correct info in email. I am getting notifications of bounces and complaints in email but without the necessary information in them.

Comment: In email they not show the to email address. Fyi goto this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html  Goto the table and read the columns (How to Access the Data,  Level of Detail)

Comment: I just went ahead and set up a simple endpoint and subscribed to an sns topic. I will watch it over the next couple of days and see if the data I need comes in. Thanks for your help and links.

Comment: This worked for me http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/bouncecomplaintdashboard.html